# How does FluentWait in Selenium implements the until() method

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriverwait, fluentwait

The syntax of the `until()` method in selenium docs is as below:

```
public <V> V until(java.util.function.Function<? super T,V> isTrue)
```

The usage of the same is like:

```
WebDriver wait = new WebDriver(driver, 20);
WebElement loginButton = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lgn-btn")));
```

I couldn't relate to the syntax and the usage of the `until()` method. I want to know how the syntax is implemented.

Yeah, I know about Generics, which we use to know about the errors at compile time so that we can avoid ClassCastException at runtime. Also, I know about the functional interface, which we use to achieve behavior parameterization.

What I didn't get is the equivalence between the `java.util.function.Function<? super T,V> isTrue)` and the `ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("id))`.

What does the expression `java.util.function.Function<? super T,V> isTrue`mean?

Comment: Do you have a question? or just wanted to share this with everybody?

Comment: I want to know how the syntax is implemented.

Comment: Not sure I understand what is the question, but `until` uses generics https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are four different topics mentioned within your question and you can find the details below:

### java.util.function

The [java.util.function](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) package includes the *Functional interfaces* which provide the target types for *lambda expressions* and method references.

A few examples are:

- `BiConsumer<T,U>`: Represents an operation that accepts two input arguments and returns no result.
- `BiFunction<T,U,R>`: Represents a function that accepts two arguments and produces a result.
- `BinaryOperator<T>`: Represents an operation upon two operands of the same type, producing a result of the same type as the operands.
- `BiPredicate<T,U>`: Represents a predicate (boolean-valued function) of two arguments.
- `Consumer<T>`: Represents an operation that accepts a single input argument and returns no result.
- `Function<T,R>`: Represents a function that accepts one argument and produces a result.

---

### Class FluentWait

The [`public class FluentWait<T>`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) class extends `java.lang.Object` and implements `Wait<T>` which implies it is an implementation of the [Wait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Wait.html) interface that may have its timeout and polling interval configured on the fly. Each FluentWait instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition, as well as the frequency with which to check the condition. Furthermore, the user may configure the wait to ignore specific types of exceptions whilst waiting, such as [NoSuchElementExceptions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/NoSuchElementException.html) when searching for an element on the page.

One of the modifier is:

```
Modifier and Type       Method and Description
-----------------       ----------------------
<V> V                   until(java.util.function.Function<? super T,V> isTrue)

Specified by:
    until in interface Wait<T>
Type Parameters:
    V - The function's expected return type.
Parameters:
    isTrue - the parameter to pass to the ExpectedCondition
Returns:
    The function's return value if the function returned something different from null or false before the timeout expired.
Throws:
    TimeoutException - If the timeout expires.
```

This implementation repeatedly applies this instance's input value to the given function until one of the following occurs:

- The function returns neither null nor false
- The function throws an unignored exception
- The timeout expires
- The current thread is interrupted

---

### Interface ExpectedCondition

The [`public interface ExpectedCondition<T>`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html) interface extends `com.google.common.base.Function<WebDriver,T>` which models a condition that is expected to evaluate to something that is neither null nor false. Examples would include determining if a web page has loaded or that an element is visible.

> Note that it is expected that `ExpectedConditions` are idempotent. They will be called in a loop by the `WebDriverWait` and any modification of the state of the application under test may have unexpected side-effects.

---

### Class ExpectedConditions

The [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) Class is the canned [ExpectedCondition](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedCondition.html)s which are generally useful within webdriver tests.

A few usage examples:

- `elementToBeClickable()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.cssSelector("element_css")));
  ```
- `visibilityOfElementLocated()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("element_css")));
  ```
- `frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("element_css")));
  ```
- `visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.cssSelector("element_css")));
  ```
- `attributeContains()`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.attributeContains(driver.findElement(my_element), "src", "https"));
  ```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please elaborate on how `until(java.util.function.Function<? super T,V> isTrue)` is equal to `until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lgn-btn")))`.

Comment: One ofthe _FluentWait_ Class modifier is `until(java.util.function.Function<? super T,V> isTrue)`. Where as `until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("lgn-btn")))` is the usage of one of the _ExpectedConditions_ Class which are the canned form of _ExpectedCondition_ interface, which actually extends `com.google.common.base.Function<WebDriver,T>`. Though the terminologies sounds similar but they are different. Take your time and browse the links embedded within. Feel free to ask in case of any doubt.